# Forced Submit when a tab is clicked

Tags: dreamweaver

I have a form with several tabs using spry tabbed panels in `Dreamweaver CS6`. I have a save button on every page which when clicked take the user to the next tab. Invariably they don't click the save button and just click the next tab and lose their changes. Is there a way I can force a submit when they click the tab ?